# SQL JOIN gives double results

Tags: mysql, sql

**My database and SQL:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebddb/1/0

---

**Problem:**

It's returning duplicates, with the wrong data in the `name`-column, when there are less than 7 records in the `notchtype`-table

---

**My Question:**

Why does it return duplicates and how to prevent it?

---

**Expected result:**

This fiddle shows the expected result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22660/1

*In this result the only thing more added than in my actual database and SQL are 2 records in the `notchtype`-table*

So the `id`, `notchid` and `number` columns should be unique in the returned rows.

The screenshot in the answer of Piyush Gupta is showing the right expected result. The same query on SQL fiddle and locally on MariaDB version 10.1.9 are returning something different

---

**Notes:**

- I found out that when there at least 7 records in the `notchtype` table, there are suddenly no duplicates anymore and the problem is 'solved'.
- The `null` values should indeed be `null`.
- The `size`-column is actually returning the right values, although the `LEFT JOIN` is more or less the same
- The ID's in `notches.notchdescr` 'connects' with the ID's in `notchtype.notchtypeid` column and is returned as the `name` column in the fiddle
- The ID's in `notches.notchsize` 'connects' with the ID's in `notchsize.notchsizeid` column and is returned as the `size` column in the fiddle

---

**Not working:**

- `INNER JOIN`, don't know why
- `DISTINCT`, because the `name`-columns have different values, so there not exact duplicates
- `GROUP BY`, because it returns all the same values in the `name`-column

---

**Update on answer/comments from Piyush Gupta**

Query executed on MySQL 5.7:

```
SELECT 
        notches.id,
        notches.notchid,
        notches.number,
        notches.xcoord,
        notches.ycoord,
        notches.mapid,
        notches.location,
        notches.date,
        notches.price,
        notches.invoiced,
        notchsize.size AS notchsize,
        notchtype.name AS notchdescr
FROM 
    notches 
LEFT JOIN
    notchtype ON
    notches.notchdescr = notchtype.notchtypeid
LEFT JOIN
    notchsize ON
    notches.notchsize = notchsize.notchsizeid
WHERE 
    notches.del = 0 
AND
    notches.projectid = '2016032411364363055'
GROUP BY notches.id, notches.notchid, notches.number
ORDER BY notches.number ASC
```

Result:

[image: Result]

---

**SOLVED!**

`LEFT JOIN` on `VARCHAR` = `BIGINT` field causes the strange returned values. See answer and comments of Piyush Gupta

Comment: You are going to need to do some aggregation using `GROUP BY`.  But you will have to tell us the logic here so we can figure out which records to use when displaying the remaining columns.

Comment: I want all the results, but without the double numbers in the id-field, notchid-field and number-field

Comment: This comment adds zero to what you already asked, or what I asked in my comment.  How do you want to decide _which_ records' values get used in the non aggregate columns?

Comment: Better post your expected result for that dataset. Then we will get the message what you want. Your last comment's confusing.

Comment: The notchdescr and notchsize columns in the notches table corresponds with the notchdescrid and notchsizeid field in the notchdescr and notchsize table

Comment: Please check this [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebddb/12/0). And let us know your expected result.

Comment: You can use GROUP BY for that like GROUP BY notches.id, notches.notchid, notches.number

Comment: Exactly that 1000111 ! That's the result i was looking for.

Comment: You missed the `GROUP BY` part in your query. ok. now it's COOL.

Comment: But why its returning double results? When i have 7 records in the notchtype-table it does'nt return double values and when have less than 7 records in that table it does return doubles?

Comment: My excusses, the column `name` in 1000111's fiddle returns all `Ronde sparing`, and it should be like my expected-result fiddle in the question

Comment: I also updated my question with better explaination of the problem, expected result and more

Comment: @RamonBakker I update one Note, check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the `GROUP BY` in your query for Aggregate the data. so your query will be,

```
SELECT 
        notches.id,
        notches.notchid,
        notches.number,
        notches.xcoord,
        notches.ycoord,
        notches.mapid,
        notches.location,
        notches.descr,
        notches.date,
        notches.price,
        notches.invoiced,
        notchtype.name AS notchdescr,
        notchsize.size AS notchsize
FROM 
    notches 
LEFT JOIN
    notchtype ON
    notches.notchdescr = notchtype.notchtypeid
LEFT JOIN
    notchsize ON
    notches.notchsize = notchsize.notchsizeid
WHERE 
    notches.del = 0 
AND
    notches.projectid = '2016032411364363055'
    GROUP BY notches.id,
        notches.notchid,
        notches.number
ORDER BY notches.number ASC;
```

**Output:**  [ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebddb/12/0)

**NOTE:** I Imported your data structure locally and I'm getting same output which is your expectation but In SQLFiddle, notchtype.name AS notchdescr column is not executing in SQLFiddle that is showing only name column of notchtype table. So you can use above query and check locally in your database. I hope you will get require output.

Screenshot(Using MySQL Workbench)
[image]

**Update 1**: It was strange error. I reviewed database structure and found solution that was data type issue only. You were joining bigint and varchar data type so you need to correct data type. Here I'm changing data type bigint to varchar for notchsizeid in notchsize table and notchtypeid in notchtype table. Finally your Expected output is coming. You can [SEE OUTPUT HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49d11/1).

Comment: It returns (locally and in the fiddle) only `Ronde sparing` in alias `notchdescr`. So its not selecting the right records from the `notchtype` table. The rest of the returned data is correct.

Comment: Omg, your screenshot indeed returns correctly! I get other results

Comment: Which MySQL Version are you using?

Comment: i updated my question with the result that my DB is giving

Comment: @RamonBakker I'm using MySQL 5.7 server not MariaDB.........On SQLFiddle Alias name is not executing so let me check that once it will fix then I'll get back

Comment: @RamonBakker Finally got the output...Check update 1 :)

Comment: Working for me now also

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using **group by** . But you need to tell your logic for this.

```
 SELECT 
        notches.id,
        notches.notchid,
        notches.number,
        notches.xcoord,
        notches.ycoord,
        notches.mapid,
        notches.location,
        notches.descr,
        notches.date,
        notches.price,
        notches.invoiced,
        notchtype.name AS notchdescr,
        notchsize.size AS notchsize
FROM 
    notches 
LEFT JOIN
    notchtype ON
    notches.notchdescr = notchtype.notchtypeid
LEFT JOIN
    notchsize ON
    notches.notchsize = notchsize.notchsizeid
WHERE 
    notches.del = 0 
AND
    notches.projectid = '2016032411364363055'
    group by id
ORDER BY notches.number ASC
```